# Syntax React: code without wrapping <div>

Tags: reactjs

How can I rewrite my code without wrapping `div`?

```
{ allItems.map(item => (
    <div>
        { item === 2 &&
        <li className="page-item">
            <span className="page-link">...</span>
        </li>
        }
        <li className="page-item">
            <span className="page-link">{item}</span>
        </li>
    </div>
))}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React 16+, you could do it with [Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html):

**In the first release, the Fragments were done by returning an Array:**

```
{ allItems.map(item => [
    { item === 2 &&
    <li className="page-item">
        <span className="page-link">...</span>
    </li>
    }
    <li className="page-item">
        <span className="page-link">{item}</span>
    </li>
])}
```

**From React 16.2+, you could use the Fragments as follows:**

```
const Fragment = React.Fragment

{ allItems.map(item => (
    <Fragment>
        { item === 2 &&
        <li className="page-item">
            <span className="page-link">...</span>
        </li>
        }
        <li className="page-item">
            <span className="page-link">{item}</span>
        </li>
    </Fragment>
))}
```

Also there's a shorthand syntax, using an empty tag:

```
const Fragment = React.Fragment

{ allItems.map(item => (
    <>
        { item === 2 &&
        <li className="page-item">
            <span className="page-link">...</span>
        </li>
        }
        <li className="page-item">
            <span className="page-link">{item}</span>
        </li>
    </>
))}
```

[Credits](http://www.deadcoderising.com/react-16-returning-multiple-children-from-a-component-using-fragments/).

Comment: @Zanetti [here's working example](https://codepen.io/mariusherring/pen/YeOpvR/), so please tune up your code to the example.

Comment: only second method came up to me, the others did not work in my code

Comment: I've updated the first example with returning the Array (just removed the parenthesis), also added shorthand syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Short syntax for `<React.Fragment>` is just empty tag; `<> </>`